# Recursively including a header file over a list of values

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, c++20

Suppose I have an header that is meant to be included several times generating code from a template parameterised over a macro `DATA`. I use it in this way:

```
#define DATA this
#include <header.hpp>
#undef DATA

#define DATA that
#include <header.hpp>
#undef DATA

#define DATA the_other
#include <header.hpp>
#undef DATA
```

Is there a way to automate this repeated inclusion given a list of the values of `DATA`? Something like:

```
#define DATAS (this, that, the_other)
#include <header.hpp>
#undef DATAS
```

I tried with some `__VA_OPT__` magic, and inside of `header.hpp` I can isolate the first element of the list and the tail of the list, but the problem is that I cannot redefine `DATAS` in terms of itself for the next inclusion.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Not possible. Depending on what's in the header, you might be able to replace it with a conventional macro.

Comment: I cannot because `header.hpp` makes other inclusions

Comment: You could perhaps include the header.hpp from another header three times. `#define DATAS (header.hpp, this, that, the_other)
#include <include3.hpp>
#undef DATAS`

Comment: can you elaborate on that? I don't get it

Comment: Write a program to generate your file. Also, put `#undef DATA` on the end of `header.hpp`.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to add a step to the build process

Comment: There are a lot of array, list, and sequence macros in Boost Preprocessor: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html If you cannot repeatedly call include, you can create a special header that includes any other header (specified) three times and sets DATA to three values one after the other.

Comment: Yes, that's limited to a fixed number of items, but it could be useful, thanks

Comment: Boost Preprocessor provides ARRAY_SIZE, LIST_SIZE and SEQ_SIZE. Recursive include is possible.

Comment: Yes I can, it’s part of my source code.

Comment: You could generalize @Sebastian's method by creating a bunch of file `include1,include2,...` that include the header once, and then include the one below. Then you could detect the number of elements in DATAS and include the concatenated result: `#include include##n`

Comment: @gigabytes oh, I didn't expect that (hence I deleted the question). Can you detail how it works, because it might be easier to change that instead?

Comment: Seems like a task for a template to me, not tricks with the preprocessor.

Comment: This is why c++ has templates. What do you have that can't be done with templates and functions?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, code that humans can read and understand without the author :)

Comment: Can you include an example of how `DATA` is used in that header?

Comment: Yes I’ll try to edit the question asap

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit I wouldn't even consider using any preprocessing tricks for that. This is a classical scripting problem.

Instead you could write a small script that creates that header for you and inserts that at the beginning of the file. You could then add that as a step in your build system to run it. This technique gives you a LOT of power going forward:

- You can add the same header to many scripts rather easily
- You can see all the custom headers in a clean json format
- You could easily get the script to add multiple `#define <key> <value>`-s before the include
- You could change formatting easily and quickly

Here is an example script that does that:

```
import json

def prepend_headers(fout, headers):
    for header in headers:
        include = header['include']
        define = header['define']

        for k, v in define.items():
            fout.write(f'#define {k} {v}\n')

        fout.write(f'#include {include}\n')

        for k, _ in define.items():
            fout.write(f'#undef {k}\n')

        fout.write('\n')

def main(configfile):
    with open(configfile) as fin:
        config = json.load(fin)

    input_file = config['input']
    with open(input_file) as fin:
        input_content = fin.read()

    output_file = config['output']
    with open(output_file, 'w') as fout:
        headers = config['headers']
        prepend_headers(fout, headers)
        fout.write(input_content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    configfile = sys.argv[1]
    sys.exit(main(configfile))
```

If you use the following configuration:

```
{
    "input": "class.cpp.template",
    "output": "class.cpp",
    "headers": [
        {
            "include": "<header.hpp>",
            "define": {
                "DATA": "this",
                "OBJ": "him"
            }
        },
        {
            "include": "<header.hpp>",
            "define": {
                "DATA": "that"
            }
        },
        {
            "include": "<header.hpp>",
            "define": {
                "DATA": "the_other"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following template file:

```
#include <iostream>

class Obj {
};

int main() {
    Obj o;
    std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result you get is this:

```
#define DATA this
#define OBJ him
#include <header.hpp>
#undef DATA
#undef OBJ

#define DATA that
#include <header.hpp>
#undef DATA

#define DATA the_other
#include <header.hpp>
#undef DATA

#include <iostream>

class Obj {
};

int main() {
    Obj o;
    std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using a template class might be annoying, so you might decide to add some hints in the output file so you could "replace" them with every build you run.

Comment: Thanks, but adding something new to the build system is not something I would consider for now. Also, this adds whatever scripting language I use as a build dependency.

Comment: @gigabytes, that is totally understandable. Though I would argue this is easily achievable even in bash, which should be a non-brainer in terms of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use Boost Preprocessor (which is independent of all other Boost Packages and only has to be downloaded, no library needs to be built or installed) to get the needed ready-to-use macros. You can also try to understand Boost Preprocessor and recreate the needed features.

The example is taken from Ari's answer. It could be expanded to provide several data elements to each iteration, e.g. for initializing the `int`s and `float`s with specific values.

```
// header.hpp - sample header, which uses DATA to create variables
// uses Boost preprocessor only for simple concatenation
// you can use your custom header here

#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>

int BOOST_PP_CAT(int_, DATA) = 1;
float BOOST_PP_CAT(float_, DATA) = 2.2f;
```

```
// main.cpp - wants to define lots of variables
// provides header name, list of symbol suffixes

// repeated.hpp will include header.hpp 3 times with DATA set to this, that and the_other
// (Space after REP_PARAMS is important)

#define REP_PARAMS ("header.hpp")(this, that, the_other)
#include "repeated.hpp"
#undef REP_PARAMS

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "int_this: " << int_this << endl;
    cout << "int_that: " << int_that << endl;
    cout << "int_the_other: " << int_the_other << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------------------"
        << endl;
    cout << "float_this: " << float_this << endl;
    cout << "float_that: " << float_that << endl;
    cout << "float_the_other: " << float_the_other << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
// repeated.hpp - helper header
// all the magic
// it mostly extracts the REP_PARAMS sequence
// TODO error-checking, e.g. that REP_PARAMS exists and is a sequence of length two, that second element of REP_PARAMS is a tuple

#if !BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING
// iteration has not started yet, include used boost headers
// initialize iteration with 3 parameters from 0 to < size of tuple,
// include itself (repeated.hpp)

#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/iterate.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/size.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/seq.hpp>

#define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1 (3, (0, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(REP_PARAMS)), "repeated.hpp"))
#include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()

#else
// set DATA to i-th element in tuple, include specified header (header.hpp)

#define DATA BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(BOOST_PP_ITERATION(), BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(REP_PARAMS))
#include BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(REP_PARAMS)
#undef DATA

#endif
```

The maximum list size is 256. By default it is limited to 64, but can be increased with the `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_TUPLE` macro.

Comment: I really think the person who implemented this boost library is probably a genius, an evil one, but still! I always find it baffling to understand how one can possibly write such code. It's as if someone is telling the same joke about job security all over again. We should write code for others to be able to read it, no matter how smart we are, and how cool we feel when we implement a feature like. And @Sebastian, this is in no way a statement that should lower the amount of respect you get for being able to implement this, but rather a personal opinion on code philosophy.

Comment: Note that the repetition is still there: https://github.com/boostorg/preprocessor/blob/develop/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/limits/forward1_1024.hpp . It's the same as writing a header that does `#include FILE` 3 times, and defining `#define FILE "header.hpp"` and including that header, just hiding the repetition in another file.

Comment: @DanielTrugman I have seen much worse (to understand) done with the preprocessor. If you remove (in thoughts) the `BOOST_PP_` prefix of each function and transform to lowercase, it get readable.

Comment: @KamilCuk With the added benefit to get a number signifying the iteration and being able to access lists by index, which makes it possible to redefine variables

Comment: That’s nice! I didn’t know Boost.Preprocessor was independent from the rest of Boost. I may give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @gigabytes It is independent in the technical sense that you need only the preprocessor directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is not doable using preprocessor only. However, it is probably worth mentioning that there is something called [X-Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) that could have been used for something close to what you are asking if you weren't using preprocessor macros for each case.

The reason is that it cannot be used here is that you cannot use `#define` or `#include` in the definition of a macro.

For example, this is doable for defining `this`, `that` and `the_other` as variables from a file called `data.def` that has them as a list:

```
// data.def
ELEMENT(this)
ELEMENT(that)
ELEMENT(the_other)
```

Then in `main.cc`:

```
//main.cc
#define ELEMENT(d) int int_##d = 1;
#include "data.def"
#undef ELEMENT

#define ELEMENT(d) int float_##d = 2.2;
#include "data.def"
#undef ELEMENT

int main() {
  std::cout << "int_this: " << int_this << std::endl;
  std::cout << "int_that: " << int_that << std::endl;
  std::cout << "int_the_other: " << int_the_other << std::endl;
  std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------"
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "float_this: " << float_this << std::endl;
  std::cout << "float_that: " << float_that << std::endl;
  std::cout << "float_the_other: " << float_the_other << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
int_this: 1
int_that: 1
int_the_other: 1
---------------------------------------------------------------
float_this: 2
float_that: 2
float_the_other: 2
```

But something like this is not going to work because you would be defining a macro in another macro:

```
#define ELEMENT(d) #define DATA d; \
#include "data.def" \
#undef DATA
#undef ELEMENT
```